# Creating a two dimensional string array

Tags: java

For the question below use 2d array greetings seen below:

![image of 2D array][1]

| "bob" | "joe" |
| --- | --- |
| "billy" | "george" |
| "janise" | "dell" |

The code that I wrote is:

```
public class c
{
// instance variables - replace the example 
below with your own
private int columns; int rows;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class c
 */
 public c()
 {
 int columns = 2;
 int rows = 3;

String[][] newArray = new String[columns][rows];
newArray[0][0] = "bob";
newArray[0][1] = "joe";

newArray[1][0] = "billy";
newArray[1][1] = "george";


newArray[1][2] = "janise";
newArray[2][2] = "dell";

for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
        System.out.println(newArray[i][j]);
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question.

Answer (score 1):

When creating the array, you need to use `new String[rows][columns]`, not `new String[columns][rows]`.

The third row should then be assigned using `newArray[2][0]` and `newArray[2][1]`.

You can use an array initializer to create the array in a much easier way:

```java
String[][] newArray = { { "hello", "ni hao" },
                        { "konnichiwa", "hola" },
                        { "guten tag", "bonjour" } };
```

Answer (score 0):

So... your code is close to being correct. 
The first mistake is that you mixed the columns and rows: You are defining your array to have two columns, but in the end, you are using three (`0, 1, 2`).
The second mistake is in the last two assignments: You really did confuse the numbering here.

Your finished constructor should look like this:

```java
int columns = 2;
int rows = 3;
String[][] newArray = new String[rows][columns];
newArray[0][0] = "hello";
newArray[0][1] = "ni hao";

newArray[1][0] = "konnichiwa";
newArray[1][1] = "hola";

newArray[2][0] = "guten tag";
newArray[2][1] = "bonjur";
    
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
        System.out.println(newArray[i][j]);
    }
}
```